# Having vertical scroll bar at the left side of the form in access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, scrollbar

I have a subform in ms-access 2010. Its scrolbar is at the right side. Does it possible to have this scrolbar at the left side?

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the subform in Form design. In the Format properties of the form, change Orientation to Right-to-Left. Save the change. Now it will appear with scrollbars on the left and record selectors on the right.  This will also reverse the order of columns, for forms in datasheet view.